# How to update `xarray.DataArray` using `.sel()` indexer?

Tags: python, database, numpy, dataframe, python-xarray

I found the easiest way to visualize creating a `N-dimensional` `DataArray` was to make a `np.ndarray` and then fill in the values by the coordinates I've created.  When I tried to actually do it, I couldn't figure out how to update the `xr.DataArray`.

**How can I update the `xr.DataArray` I've initialized using the labels I've created?** My actual data is a much more complicated dataset but this sums up what I'm trying to do. I can use `.loc` but sometimes my `ndarrays` get huge and complicated where I don't really know the order of the dims.

```
# Construct DataArray
DA = xr.DataArray(np.ndarray((3,3,5)), dims=["axis_A","axis_B","axis_C"], coords={"axis_A":["A_%d"%_ for _ in range(3)],
                                                                                  "axis_B":["B_%d"%_ for _ in range(3)],
                                                                                 "axis_C":["C_%d"%_ for _ in range(5)]})
# <xarray.DataArray (axis_A: 3, axis_B: 3, axis_C: 5)>
# array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

#        [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

#        [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
# Coordinates:
#   * axis_B   (axis_B) <U3 'B_0' 'B_1' 'B_2'
#   * axis_A   (axis_A) <U3 'A_0' 'A_1' 'A_2'
#   * axis_C   (axis_C) <U3 'C_0' 'C_1' 'C_2' 'C_3' 'C_4'

# # Update? 
DA.sel(axis_A="A_1", axis_B="B_1", axis_C="C_1").values = 1
DA.max()
# # <xarray.DataArray ()>
# # array(0.0)

DA.sel(axis_A="A_1", axis_B="B_1", axis_C="C_1") = 1
# #  File "<ipython-input-17-8feb7332633f>", line 4
# #     DA.sel(axis_A="A_1", axis_B="B_1", axis_C="C_1") = 1
# #                                                         ^
# # SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is really awkward, due to the unfortunate limitation of Python syntax that keyword arguments are not supported in inside square bracket.

So instead, you need to put the arguments to `.sel` as a dictionary in `.loc` instead:

```
DA.loc[dict(axis_A="A_1", axis_B="B_1", axis_C="C_1")] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks again @Stephan ! I saw that syntax on http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html but wasn't aware you could update in that way.

Comment: I had missed this option about indexing to assign. I don't think it's anywhere in the help. I might add it

Comment: see https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2055 for discussion of how we should fix up the docs

Comment: Thanks. What about `.sel`'s `method='nearest'` ability? I'd like to change the value of a grid cell which is sitting over a particular lat/lon point... And that lat/lon point is of course not in the co-ord variable so I get a KeyError without `method='nearest'`.